# interpolation on pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, interpolation

I need to do **interpolation** between 2 columns of `pandas.DataFrame`, to fill the column between them. 
Here are a few rows of my `data frame`, the column to be filled is `col2`:

```
col1  col2  col3
2.35    1   2.37
2.47    1   2.49
2.51    1   2.53
2.57    1   2.58
2.54    1   2.57
```

So for interpolation I want to use `numpy.interp(x,xp,fp)`, but I can't figure out how to organize my data so that I will be able to use it. That is because the interpolation should be between `col1` and `col3` **for each row.**
For example, for the first row I need it to look like that:

```
xp=[1,3]
fp=[2.47,2.49]
x=2
y=numpy.interp(x,xp,fp)
```

and then fill first row of `col2` with `y`. And I need to do that again and again for each row.
How ?

Comment: Linear interpolation between two values is just the mean...or did I miss something?

Comment: right here in this example it is the average, but later I need to fill columns 8,9 by columns 7 and 10, so I do need to use interpolation.

Comment: `xp=[1,3]` - where do the 1 and 3 come from?

Comment: 1 is `col1` and 3 is `col3`

Comment: @SharonAsayag I updated my answer below.  Still, you can do the linear interpolation yourself without multiple calls to numpy.interp, which should be slow.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you to iterate over every row, replacing the value between two cells. But the interpolation does not seem to be working. I don't have much experience with it, so I couldn't find an easy fix online. That's the only line not doing the change of values. (Idon't know what xp or x do, so I kept them)

```
xp=[1,3]
x = 2
for rowNr in range(len(df.index)):
    fp=[df.iat[rowNr, 0], df.iat[rowNr, 2]]
    df.iat[rowNr, 1] = numpy.interp(x, xp, fp)
```

Comment: I got only ints... for all rows I got 2.

Comment: I tried float(numpy.interp(x, xp, fp)) and it didn't help. any idea?

Comment: Yeah, it outputs only ints the way it is. Just read the comments and the other reply, and I think it has to do with the interpolation. I don't know how it works, but if you use "xp=[1,3]", that is simply a list of two integers which you feed as the x-coordinates. Whereas, in my example, fp, -the y coordinates were [2.35, 2.37]. One is not like the other. If you interpolate with x=2 on xp=2.35 and fp=2.37, you get 2.37 as the value in the middle. This is just all my trial and error, as I don't know what interpolation is, but I'm fairly sure it does not work the way you need it, atm.

Answer (score 0):

As written, the x-values are static (unless I misunderstand your problem) with values of 1 and 3.  You want to do a linear interpolation between these values and two y-values that change.  You simply average the y-values and that is the linear-interpolated value.  Don't overlook simple/obvious solutions for something fancy (advice I try to remember all the time).

```
df.col2 = df[["col1", "col3"]].mean(axis=1)
```

### BEGIN EDIT

Andre's solution should work (haven't tested it myself, but should).  However, this requires iterating over every row, which can be slow.  Further, there is a simple mathematical solution that allows you to operate on arrays, which should be faster.

Linear interpolation follows the general form of:

```
y = y0 + (x - x0) * (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)
```

Putting this in terms of dataframes/code:

```
df.col2 = df.col1 + (x - xp[0]) * (df.col2 - df.col1) / (xp[1] - xp[0])
```

I think that got translated correctly, but the formula above holds.  Just implement it in your code or loop through each row and call the numpy.interp function.  Either way, you should be fine.